# Skip values for which Python generator raises Exception?

Tags: python, generator

Imagine I have a very simple generator, that I cannot modify for whatever reason. Say,

```
>>> g = (1/x for x in [1, 1, 0, 0, 2])
```

My goal is to obtain all the valid data. However, trying to print the list,

```
>>> print(list(g))
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Is it possible to write a "wrapper" function such that,

```
>>> print(list(wrapper(g)))
[1.0, 1.0, 0.5]
```

?

Comment: Use `try/catch` inside the generator.

Comment: for the purposes of the question, assume the generator cannot be changed

Comment: The answer is no.  See the duplicate.  If the original generator raises an exception, then the original generator itself stops then and never reaches later values, so there's nothing you can do externally to get at those values.  The later values never actually exist.

Comment: I was asked a similar question to this one in a job interview, so I figured that answer was wrong / outdated somehow.

I guess not!